# Spy function into computed get

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I'm trying to spy methods into computed properties :

```
time() {
  get() {
    let time = this.winLimitByType(this.gameId, this.winLimitType, this.timeRangeIndex)[this.timeType];

    if (time) {
      time = time.slice(0, 5);

      if (this.timeType === TO_TIME) {
        time = this.getRealTimeToDisplay(time);
      }
    }

    return time;
  },

  set(value) {
    ...
  }
}
```

When I run test :

```
  const wrapper = factory(WinLimitType.AMOUNT_IN_TIME_SLOTS_DAY,
    OperationObjectGenerator.generateTimeRange('number', '10:00', '11:59:00'), 'toTime');

  const spyGetRealTimeToDisplay = jest.spyOn(wrapper.vm, 'getRealTimeToDisplay');

  wrapper.vm.time;

  expect(spyGetRealTimeToDisplay).toBeCalledWith('11:59');
```

Got the error :

> Expected mock function to have been called with:
>         ["11:59"]
>       But it was not called.

Is there a way to test it ?

Thanks.

Comment: You are not calling time method. () missing aftet time.  Should be wrapper.vm.time()

Comment: time is a computed property, () is not missing. When I call with (), I got the error : 'wrapper.vm.time is not a function'

Comment: When I store the result of wrapper.vm.time (Example : const result = wrapper.vm.time), I got the good result. But nothing append with spy.

Comment: Try toHaveBeenCalledWith(). That's the function jest offer.

Comment: toHaveBeenCalledWith() is an alias of toBeCalledWith(). Same result expected.

Comment: I think as you are saying if you assign const and then it working with good result. This should work. if  you have some working demo then can investigate further